# threw exception java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, java-ee, servlet

Вызывается ошибка, использую CD-зависимости. Сервер Apache 8.5, cdi-api-1.2, weld-servlet-2.2.14.

```
    SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [ru.unlimit.Game] in context with path [/Test] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

На эту строку

```
  if(cardIgra.getPlayer().getArrayCard().size() == 5)
```

Хотя экземпляр класса должен создаваться сам на сервере

```
@Inject CardIgra cardIgra;
```

Реализация класса

```
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class CardIgra implements Serializable {
//методы
}
```

Comment: А ведь не факт, что именно `cardIgra` - `null`. Возможно, `null`-ом является значение, возвращаемое методом `getPlayer` или `getArrayCard`. Для начала стоит разобраться что именно является `null`-ом.

Comment: да, было нулевое. Нашел решение. Сча добавлю

Comment: Решение стоит опубликовать ответом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**РЕШЕНИЕ**

Нужно добавить в каталог WEB-INF файл beans.xml`

```
encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
       bean-discovery-mode="annotated">
</beans>`
```